# Prevent RAM from paging to swap area (mlock)

Tags: python, memory, posix, ram

Is there a way to call [the POSIX `mlock` function](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/2/MLOCK/) from Python? The effect of `mlock` is to disable swapping out certain objects.

I know there are still other issues when it comes to securing cryptographic keys, I just want to know how to contain them in RAM.

Comment: I found this [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/s-data.html?n-s-311) document relevant / interesting with regards to memory locking and mutability in Python

Comment: Very interesting read. Disabling core dumps is well explained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For CPython, there is no good answer for this that doesn't involve writing a Python C extension, since `mlock` works on pages, not objects. Even if you used `ctypes` to retrieve the necessary addresses and `mlock`-ed them all through `ctypes` `mlock` calls, you'll have a hell of a time determining when to `mlock` and when to `munlock`. You'd need to know the memory address and sizes of all protected data types; since `mlock` works on pages, you'd have to carefully track how many objects are currently in any given page (because if you just `mlock` and `munlock` blindly, and there are more than one things to lock in a page, the first `munlock` would unlock all of them; `mlock/munlock` is a boolean flag, it doesn't count the number of locks and unlocks).

Even if you manage that, you still would have a race between data acquisition and `mlock` during which the data could be written to swap.

You could partially avoid these problems through careful use of the `mmap` module and `memoryview`s (`mmap` gives you pages of memory, `memoryview` references said memory without copying it, so `ctypes` could be used to `mlock` the page), but you'd have to build it all from scratch.

In short, Python doesn't care about swapping or memory protection in the way you want; it trusts the swap file to be configured to your desired security (e.g. disabled or encrypted), neither providing additional protection nor providing the information you'd need to add it in.