# mlock a variable in python

Tags: python, swap, system-calls

I'm working on a password manager application for linux and I'm using Python for it.

Because of the security reasons I want to call ‍`mlock‍‍` system call in order to avoid swapping password variable on hard drive.

I noticed that python itself didn't wrap this function.

so is there any way so can I avoid swapping?

Thanks

Comment: Basically the same question as [mlock an object from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524020/mlock-an-object-from-python) (unanswered at present) and related to [Mark data as sensitive in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982682/mark-data-as-sensitive-in-python).

Comment: // , Can you mlock() the whole Python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CPython, there is no good answer for this that doesn't involve writing a Python C extension, since `mlock` works on pages, not objects. The internals of the `str` object differ from version to version (in Py3.3 and higher, a `str` may actually have several copies of the data in memory in different encodings, some inlined after the object structure, some dynamically allocated separately and linked by pointer), and even if you used `ctypes` to retrieve the necessary addresses and `mlock`-ed them all through `ctypes` `mlock` calls, you'll have a hell of a time determining when to `mlock` and when to `munlock`. Since `mlock` works on pages, you'd have to carefully track how many strings are currently in any given page (because if you just `mlock` and `munlock` blindly, and there are more than one things to lock in a page, the first `munlock` would unlock all of them; `mlock/munlock` is a boolean flag, it doesn't count the number of locks and unlocks).

Even if you manage that, you still would have a race between password acquisition and `mlock` during which the data could be written to swap, and those cached alternate encodings are computed lazily, so `mlock`ing the non-`NULL` pointers at any given time doesn't necessarily mean the currently `NULL` pointers might not be populated later.

You could partially avoid these problems through careful use of the `mmap` module and `memoryview`s (`mmap` gives you pages of memory, `memoryview` references said memory without copying it, so `ctypes` could be used to `mlock` the page), but you'd have to build it all from scratch (can't use the `getpass` module because it would store as a `str` for a moment).

In short, Python doesn't care about swapping or memory protection in the way you want; it trusts the swap file to be configured to your desired security (e.g. disabled or encrypted), neither providing additional protection nor providing the information you'd need to add it in.