# Can Python end up saving temp data in disk instead of memory on its own?

Tags: python, security, ram

I want to make a simple password manager.

If I open an encrypted file with `open()` and decrypt it into a variable, could the decrypted data somehow touch the disk in this process?

Obviously I wouldn't want such data to leave the memory.

Comment: Yes, if the OS decides to move memory content to a swap file or partition.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524020/prevent-ram-from-paging-to-swap-area-mlock